# "ValueError: The input contains nan values" when using lmfit

Tags: python, compiler-errors, lmfit

I'm using `lmfit` to fit a four parameter logistic curve to my data, with my current code as follows:

```
import matplotlib, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model

def pl(x, a, b, c, d):
    return (a - d) / (1+ (x / c) ** b) + d

x = [-4.522878745,
    -5.22184875,
    -5.920818754,
    -6.619788758,
    -7.318758763,
    -8.017728767,
    -8.716698771,
    -9.415668776,
    ]

y = [12,
    6,
    37,
    10297,
    22635,
    24279,
    25666,
    24365]


mod = Model(pl)
params = mod.make_params(a = 25000, b = 2, c = 1, d = 0)
result = mod.fit(y, params, x=x)
print(result.fit_report())


plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', markersize = 1.5)
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, color = 'red', linewidth = 0.5)
plt.show()
```

However, this gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\George\OneDrive\Subjects\EE\Regression.py", line 29, in <module>
    result = mod.fit(y, params, x=x)
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\lmfit\model.py", line 1007, in fit
    output.fit(data=data, weights=weights)
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\lmfit\model.py", line 1355, in fit
    _ret = self.minimize(method=self.method)
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\lmfit\minimizer.py", line 1949, in minimize
    return function(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\lmfit\minimizer.py", line 1492, in leastsq
    lsout = scipy_leastsq(self.__residual, variables, **lskws)
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 396, in leastsq
    gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\lmfit\minimizer.py", line 538, in __residual
    nan_policy=self.nan_policy)
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\lmfit\minimizer.py", line 2166, in _nan_policy
    raise ValueError("The input contains nan values")
ValueError: The input contains nan values
```

One thing I noticed, however, is if I change the paramater `c` to `0`, the error disappears, but is replaced with the following error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\George\OneDrive\Subjects\EE\Regression.py", line 5
    return (a - d) / (1+ (x / c) ** b) + d
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
```

Additionally, the 'curve' is simply a straight line:

[image]

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Fitting with `lmfit` or `scipy.optimize` (or most other approaches to "fitting data") assume the data, the best-fit model, and all the parameters are real numbers.  Your model function contains `(1+ (x / c) ** b)` with `x` being negative, `c` being a value that might be adjusted in the fit, and both `b` and `c` being real numbers.

But, of course `negative_number**fractional_real` (say `(-2.3)**3.4`) is a complex number.  The fitting algorithms cannot handle those.

So, you'll have to decide how to handle the possibilities of complex numbers.  The suggestion to use `(x/c)**int(b)` might seem attractive, but would mean the fit would not be able to find the value of `b` -- the fit will make small adjustments to each parameter value and since `int(2.0) = int(2.000001)`, it will determine that small changes to `b` do not alter the fit.  That said, you could simply run the fit keeping `b` fixed to integer values between 0 and 10 and decide which fit works best.

Anyway, that all assumes that your model function describes your data and is what you actually want to use.  I think your model may not describe your data well, and that you would be better off using an actual logistic function.  Making use of the models built into lmfit, this might look like:

```
from lmfit.models import StepModel, ConstantModel 

mod = StepModel(form='logistic') + ConstantModel()
params = mod.make_params(amplitude=-20000, center=-7, sigma=1, c=20000)

result = mod.fit(y, params, x=x)
print(result.fit_report())
```

For your data, this will give best-fit parameter values of `sigma ~= 0.24`,`center ~= -6.7`, `amplitude ~= -25000`, and `c ~= 25000`, and a plot that looks decent.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the value of `b` is modified each time your handler function is called internally. The value of `b` increases in its precision with each iteration, until it gets so large it causes the `**` operation to fall over producing `nan`s (internally it's numpy evaluating `**`). At the point that it falls over, the value of `b` on my machine is `2.0000000298023224`.

You could ensure that `b` is always an integer at the point of calculation:

```
def pl(x, a, b, c, d):
    return (a - d) / (1+ (x / c) ** int(b)) + d
```